# How can I make this url valid for emails?

Tags: validation, email, hyperlink

I have a link in an email, this link is generated from the site the email is sent from.
People go to the site to vote on something and then they get an email with the link to confirm their vote.

The link in the mail is generated from this:

```
http://www.domain.com/vote?Q=QAPmail&d=<# Responder.RespID #>&k=<# Responder.AccessKey #>
```

The generated link, the one that ends up in the mailbox looks something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/vote?&Q=QAPmail&d=78874058&k=betyzucp
```

The variables in the link are required to make the vote unique so I can't remove those parts.

On all my test cases (various email providers and such) it works fine, however I've been getting some complaints from people who aren't able to open the link.

In most cases either "x-msg://" or "wlmailhtml:" is added in front of the link, which makes the mail provider state that it's an invalid/insecure link when clicked on.

I'm not sure why this link would be invalid, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The link seems valid. Are those people able to copy-paste the link? If they can, than you could make the email body html and simple add  tag, like so:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/...">http://www.domain.com/...</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They are able to copy paste the link and visit the correct confirmation page from there. 
However the email is already a html mail, the link is already added as an a-tag.

Comment: You might also try encoding URL using [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx), something like this: ...&d=<# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Responder.RespID) #>...